# ListFragment images change size

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `ListFragment` with a custom `ListAdapter` that lazy loads images and displays a view with the image on the left and some text on the right.  The custom list item I'm using looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:maxWidth="80dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is all working fine, but when I click a list item and then click back, most times the list displays with the images at their full size, not at 80dp width as specified.  If I wait a while before pressing back, the list sometimes loads correctly.

Does anyone know how I could fix this?  I want the images to always display at 80dp width.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I use images with different widths and heights. Force every image to 85x85, cropped.

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/some_img"
        android:layout_width="85dip"
        android:layout_height="85dip"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" 
    />
```

You might consider using either centerCrop or centerInside.

I wouldn't be surprised if `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` is causing the issue you are seeing.

Another possible culprit is that you are setting `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` in the `TextView` which should be `wrap_content`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  I don't want to crop the image, I want to scale it.  The `adjustViewBounds` is to make sure that the `ImageView` only takes up as much space as the scaled image, otherwise it will retain the original image's proportions.  The `TextView` has its height set to `fill_parent` so I can vertically centre it - although this shuld also be possible with `wrap_text` and `layout_gravity` - which I'll try now

Comment: No changing from `fill_parent` to `wrap_content` didn't help, the images still keep scaling back to full size.

Comment: I tried removing `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`, but that made no difference

Comment: OK so I had a look at centerCrop and see it is supposed to scale the image.  However, I tried your code and with it the images are always displayed at full size.  Do you think it might be the lazy loading that's causing the problem, rather than the layout properties?

Comment: Just to be clear, your tried using fixed heights/widths (eg 85dip x 85dip) with `centerCrop` (without adjustViewBounds) and are still seeing the resize issue? How are you setting the image once you are done loading it?

Comment: Never mind - I tried your code again and it worked this time! Thanks for your help :)